# Referenced Project's Files Not Included in Referencing Project

Tags: asp.net, .net, reference

I Have a solution with 2 projects, one is an ASP.Net project, the other is a class library. The class library depends on a file being included to run. The ASP.Net project depends on the class library to run.

I set the file needed by the class to a `Build Action` of "Content" and a `Copy to Output Directory` of "Copy if newer" and sure enough, the output directory of my class (`bin\Debug` or `bin\Release`) shows the file I need.

When I add this class as a reference to my ASP.Net project, the extra file I need, the "Content" file, isn't included, only the `.dll`, `.pdb`, and `.xml` files, and other dependent libraries are included in the ASP.Net project. How do I get my "Content" file to also be copied over to the ASP.Net folder like the other files in the `bin\Release` folder are?

I thought this answer would help, but I'm not working with tests. ([Xml file not copying to test output directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369861/xml-file-not-copying-to-test-output-directory))

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the content file should be copied across. Have you tried to mark it as `Copy Always`?

Anyway, if that does not work, it might be beneficial to enable better diagnostics from your build. Eg:

1. Go to `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Projects and Solutions` ->  `Build and Run` settings.
2. Change `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to `Normal`.
3. Make sure `On Run, when projects are out of date` is set to `Always build.`
4. When you build inspect the **_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory** task (the copy task)

Refer to this question here:
[File marked as Content -> Copy Always is not being copied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441513/file-marked-as-content-copy-always-is-not-being-copied)

Comment: I've tried `Copy Always` and that makes no difference. I've also tried as you suggested (which I didn't even know I could do) and found that indeed the file is being copied to the output directory of the library, but I see no copy activity showing any class library files being copied to any part of the ASP.Net projects directory structure.